# Feature matching between segmented images

Tags: matching, feature-detection, sift, semantic-segmentation, orb

I would like to improve the feature matching between two images by using a pre-trained semantic segmentation model. Of course I am familiar with the ORB or SIFT features and matching with OpenCV in python, but I am curious if it is possible to further improve that by using a precise semantic segmentation model. The purpose of this is I would like to calculate the epipolar geometry between 2 images. Does it make any sense to do that? Is there any algorithm that does that? I could not find anything on the internet.

Comment: How do you think that semantic segmentation will help ?

Comment: By extracting exact location and edges of the objects

Comment: Have you thought of the problem of matching two outlines ? And what if the segmentation finds three "cats" in the two images ?

Comment: Well, that could be solved by trying to find the best match, using some thresholds

Comment: That "could" work. Good luck.

Comment: Wow, so salty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to go all the way to hard-decisions on semantic boundaries to enrich your correspondences with semantic information.
You can replace SIFT/ORB, which are low-level features, with semantic descriptors, such as DINO-ViT features. Check out [this](https://github.com/ShirAmir/dino-vit-features) project page and see how these features can be used for establishing semantic correspondences between images.

Comment: Thank you! That was exaclty the kind of answer I was looking for